# Tchebyshev polynomials and ||T_n(x)||

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Hilbert space of functions $f:[-1,1] \to \mathcal{C}$ equipped with the inner product defined by 
$$\forall f,g \in \mathcal{H}, <f,g>= \int^1_{-1} \frac{f(x)\overline{g(x)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $$

Let the Tchebyshev polynomials defined by 
   $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, T_n(x)=\cos(n \theta)  \text{ where } \cos \theta = x \text{ and } 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi $$
show that $||T_0 || ] = \sqrt{\pi}$ and $|| T_n||=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ for $n\geq 1$

---

**showing that $|| T_0||=\sqrt{\pi}$**

$T_0(x)=cos(0)=1$  (not sure what to do with $cos \theta =x $ right now)
So, $||T_0 ||=\sqrt{<1,1>}$

We have that 
$$\begin{aligned}
<1,1>&= \int^1_{-1} \frac{1*\overline{1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx 
 \\  &= \int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
 \\ &= [arcsin(x)]^1_-{1} 
\\ &= \pi
 \end{aligned}$$

Making that $\sqrt{<1,1>}=\sqrt{\pi}$

**for n=1** $T_1(x)=cos(1*\theta)=cos(1*arccos(x))=x$
so $$ || T_1(x)||^2= <x,x>=\int^{1}_{-1} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = $$

---

Trying to use induction somehow. But I am not sure if I am on the right track. Appreciate comments thanks!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have,
$$\lVert T_n\rVert^{2} = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{T_n(x)\overline{T_n(x)}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\operatorname{d}\!x.$$

When $ x= \cos(\theta)$, $dx = -\sin(\theta)\operatorname{d}\!\theta$ and $n\geq 1$,

$$\lVert T_n\rVert^{2} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos^{2}(n\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^{2}(\theta)}}\sin(\theta)\operatorname{d}\!\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{2}(n\theta)\operatorname{d}\!\theta.$$

It's well known that from Fourier Analysis that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^{2}(n\theta)\operatorname{d}\!\theta = \pi$$

hence

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{2}(n\theta)\operatorname{d}\!\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

The only thing left is for you to write down the details for the above integral and take the square root.